# How to get meaningful alias or name for provisioned service in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, administration, ibm-appid

I am using the CLI command `bx service create` to provision a new service. Some of the services support resource groups. For them, I noticed that the service itself has a long generic name and is listed under "Services". The name I chose is only associated with an alias, listed under "Cloud Foundry Services".

How can I get those services to use the name I picked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use [another IBM Cloud CLI command](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/bx_cli.html#bluemix_cli). It is part of the set of commands to manage resource groups and its objects:

```
bx resource service-instance-create
```

Using the above command, the name is used for the service and there is no alias created. The service is only listed under "Services". Here is a full example:

```
bx resource service-instance-create ghstatsDDE dynamic-dashboard-embedded lite us-south
```